# 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array error in R

Tags: r

I already loaded the data set and now Im getting this:

```
defaults <- ifelse(defaults == "no", 0, 1)
set.seed(123)
train_idx <- sample(nrow(defaults), .70*nrow(defaults))
defaults_train <- defaults[train_idx,]
defaults_test <- defaults[-train_idx,]
mod1 <- glm(Y ~ LIMIT_BAL + BILL_AMT1 + PAY_AMT6, family = binomial, data=defaults_train)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ LIMIT_BAL + BILL_AMT1 + PAY_AMT6,  :
> 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

Any idea how to fix this to not get the error?

Comment: What is `class(defaults_train)` and `class(defaults)` ?

Answer (score 0):

check the class of defaults (class(defaults)),train_idx and defaults_train. Is your loaded dataset named defaults?